# Passing textbox data between forms in ASP MVC causes validation at page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form that sends data to another form. Like page 1 would have your zip code and you hit next. That would direct you to page 2 displaying the zip in a textbox along with other input fields like address, city and state.

The problem is when the data is passed it triggers my mvc validation when the user lands on the page. So Address and City are already highlighted red. What steps can I use to fix this issue?

***The validation was fixed no data is passed, data is hitting the view inputs but no data is sent

> page 1, sends data to form SellYourHouse

```
 @model myModel.Models.AsideModel
 @using (@Html.BeginForm("quoteModel1", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmSell1", id = "frmSell1" }))
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName, "", new { @class = "name-sm", @placeholder = "First Name" })<br />
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lastName, "", new { @class = "name-sm", @placeholder = "Last Name" })<br/>
   Other inputs not shown for less content........
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Offer" class="btn2" /> </div>

   }
```

> SellYourHouse, receives data from action quoteModel1

```
   @model myModel.Models.quoteModel
   @using (@Html.BeginForm("SellYourHouse", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmSell", id = "frmSell" }))
                {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.address, "", new { @class = "name-sm", @placeholder = "Address" })<br /><br />
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.city, "", new { @class = "name-sm", @placeholder = "City" })<br />
    }
```

> model that send the data

```
public class AsideModel
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string DdlState { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public int zip { get; set; }
}
```

> model that receives the data

```
 public class quoteModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Required")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = " Invalid phone number")]
    public string phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = " Valid email required")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Required")]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Required")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
    public string DdlState { get; set; } 

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = " *")]
    public string zip { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
    public string bedrooms { get; set; }

    public string additional { get; set; }
 }

}
```

> controller that sends the data

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult quoteModel1(AsideModel model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SellYourHouse", new {FirstName = model.firstName, LastName = model.lastName, Address = model.address, DDLState = model.DdlState, Zip = model.zip});

    }
```

> controller that receives the data

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SellYourHouse(quoteModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Email code with the rest of the forms
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 forms for this? You need 2 separate models and 2 separate post methods to handle this correctly (and follow the PRG pattern in the 1st post method)

Comment: Thanks I testing it now

Comment: updated my answer you know why i'm not getting my data passed? I think its something with my View. My break point show something is being sent to SellYourHouse page but no data is passed into the textbox

Comment: Both you forms post to `SellYourHouse()` - I assume the first one should post to `quoteModel1()`? And you 2nd form does not have an input or route value for `zip` (so it cannot send its value). But why are you using 2 pages for this instead of one?

Comment: Okay I updated my question, I forgot to update the view. The view part should be updated now. I'm making an aside on every page of a site that ask the user for 6 questions. Which collects and send data to the main page asking for an additional 9 questions. Or the user can go straight to the main page and fill out the whole form. The second form might be what I'm missing; what do you mean about "route value" and "input" im missing?

Comment: Also don't use placeholders as replacement for labels.  see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-placeholder

Comment: In your _controller that sends the data_ you pass a value for `zip` to a `SellYourHouse()` GET method (you have not shown that), but in the view it generates (the 2nd form you have shown) you do not have a hidden input for `zip`, so it will never be submitted to your `SellYourHouse()` POST method - if you need it then you need to include `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.zip)` in that form

Answer (score 0):

Split up your model and controller actions.

Split view models

```
public class QuoteModelStep1
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = " *")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteModelStep2
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Required")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " Required")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Zip { get; set; }


}
```

Split controller actions

```
    public ActionResult Step1()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Step1(QuoteModelStep1 model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Step2", new {zip = model.Zip});
    }

    public ActionResult Step2(string zip)
    {
        var model = new QuoteModelStep2 {Zip = zip};

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Step2(QuoteModelStep2 model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

For the Step2 GET method, the zip will be passed as a query string, but you don't have to do that. you could use TempData or Session to store it so that you don't see it on the url.

I has visual studio generate my Step1 and Step2 views from the Add view wizard passing in the correct view model.

Stepped through the code in the debugger and I'm seeing the zip get passed from Step1 to Step2 and the form data from Step2 getting POST'ed correctly.

Comment: thanks I'm testing it now, trying to figure out why step1 isn't sending to step2, i'm just getting redirected to the page step2

Comment: For some reason its not linking up with page 2. Breakpoints show it's hitting form 2, but no data is being passed. Seems like I need to link my AsideModel to the view as well. I'm not sure

Comment: updated my answer you know why i'm not getting my data passed? I think its something with my View. My break points show something is being sent to SellYourHouse page but no data is passed into the textbox